# IntelliJ NodeJS Debugging Callback Scope Reference Error

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, scope, callback

I'm debugging a NodeJS application in Intellij. I have a method that looks as follows:

```
function(connection) {
  connection.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('there is an error'); // breakpoint is on this line
  });
}
```

When the breakpoint is hit, `connection` is not defined, and putting `connection` in the Evaluate Expression window yields "ReferenceError: connection is not defined."

It appears to me that `connection` is being deallocated because it's not being used within the callback, but I'm debugging the application, so how can I make it not be deallocated, short of adding the line `localConnection = connection` (which does work).

Here's another example:

```
var foo = (function() {
  var a = 'some value';
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar'); // breakpoint is here
  };
  this.bar();
})();
```

Here, `a` is inaccessible from the debugger.

**EDIT**:

To clarify the second example, `a` is private to methods declared outside of `foo`, but not otherwise. Case in point:

```
var foo = (function() {
  var a = 'Some value';
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log('a: ' + a); // breakpoint is here
  };
  this.bar();
})();
```

This example does print "a: Some value," suggesting that `a` should be accessible within the line. And as a matter of fact, simply by adding it in the console log, it does stay accessible in that line, which suggests that its previous inaccessibility was due to garbage collection or reference counting, which, in a debugging environment, I would like to be less rigorous, because I would like to maintain the ability to see the values of variables that are not necessarily used in code at debug-time.

The same applies to the first example. When using `connection` inside the callback in code, it's exposed to the debugger, but I'm trying to make it stay exposed even without code usage. How do I do that? I'm quite positive there is a runtime flag for Node to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

First example, connection is an event emitter. so the outer function has already been finished to work when "error" event occurs. So you can not get it back. second example is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and "a" is somewhat a private variable even if does not look like that way.

You can use a global variable to access both of them. I know this looks like a dirty workaround. but it works anyway, here is an example:

```js
var m;
function(connection) {
  m = connection;
  connection.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('there is an error'); // breakpoint is on this line
    console.log(m); // now you can access connection
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid that's not the case though. Please see my edit.